# How to get count of last null values rows of column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which gives me output like

```
RowId   StartTime             EndTime   
1   2014-03-12 04:44:20.100    NULL 
2   2014-03-12 04:44:20.100    2014-03-18 06:46:24.193  
3   2014-03-18 06:53:05.590    NULL 
4   2014-03-18 06:53:05.590    NULL
```

Now i want as you can see the 3rd and 4th rows have `null value` and these are last rows after `'Endtime'` column has value .. so it should be return me `2 count.`

How can i get this output. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all rows that have null `EndTime` and start after last (max) `EndTime`, you can use:

```
select count(RowId)
from table1
where StartTime > (select MAX(EndTime) from table1)
and EndTime IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as count 
from table 
order by Starttime desc 
group by Starttime 
having EndTime=Null
```